# Помогите исправить ошибки в пунктуации, если они есть

Tags: пунктуация

1. В доме были: Иванов, Петров, Сидоров и, конечно, я сам.
2. В доме были: Иванов, Петров, Сидоров и конечно же я сам.
3. В доме были: Иванов, Петров, Сидоров, ну и конечно я сам.
4. В доме были: Иванов, Петров, Сидоров, ну и конечно же я сам.

И объясните, пожалуйста, почему правильно или неправильно? Я сам запутался.

Answer (score 1):

1) В доме были: Иванов, Петров, Сидоров и, конечно, я сам.

2) В доме были: Иванов, Петров, Сидоров и, конечно же, я сам.

3) В доме были: Иванов, Петров, Сидоров, ну и конечно я сам.

4) В доме были: Иванов, Петров, Сидоров, ну и конечно же я сам.

Пояснение

КОНЕЧНО,  КОНЕЧНО ЖЕ - это вводные слова. Сочетания НУ И КОНЕЧНО, НУ И КОНЕЧНО ЖЕ - также вводные сочетания, но здесь они выступают в роли присоединительного союза перед "я сам" и поэтому не обособляются.

Вообще говоря,  вводные слова КОНЕЧНО, КОНЕЧНО ЖЕ могут являться  необособленными частицами, если придают уверенность слову, к которому они относятся.

То же самое можно сказать о сочетаниях И КОНЕЧНО, НУ И КОНЕЧНО, И КОНЕЧНО ЖЕ, НУ И КОНЕЧНО ЖЕ: они могут являться вводными словами, частицами, а также возможны варианты с обособлением: НУ И, КОНЕЧНО, НУ И, КОНЕЧНО ЖЕ. Соответственно, возможны разные авторские варианты оформления подобных выражений, например:

Есть, конечно же, узкий круг, с которым мы общаемся постоянно.

Ну и конечно же, здесь царил вечный спутник российского литератора ― алкоголь. И конечно же, весь мир надеялся на трудолюбивый Китай.

Ну и конечно же взять ответственность на самих себя. Ну и конечно же посетим Алмазный фонд! И конечно же присутствует доверие, иначе быть не может.

Ну и, конечно же, для этого нужна особая методика.